# Wireshark guidance, I installed it but can't detect any interface. It seems my winPcap is not installed right, any suggestions?

Tags: wireshark, packet, winpcap

Basically I've installed wireshark on widows 10, but so far no interface is detected on my computer. Do I need to reinstall my wincap?

my winPcap error says:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32|drivers\npf.sys

click abort to stop the intsalltion,

retry again or ignore skip the file
```

I already done this step:

```
opening a command prompt as administrator (Win+R > cmd > Enter)
navigate to \windows\syswow64
delete Packet.dll
reboot
Install new version of Winpcap
```

Do I need to delete npf.sys?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that Winpcap can't be installed because it doesn't have any permission to edit the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32|drivers\npf.sys`.

All you have to do is right-click on `npf.sys < Properties < Security < Edit` and check full control and all the other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that problem using the cmd window.
Check whether your npf status is "stopped" or not.
You can check your npf status by typing

> 'sc query npf'

If that status is "stopped", then you have to change it to "running".
You can change that status by typing

> 'sc start npf'